# How to change text color in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, styles, data-visualization

How to change the color of a matplotlib graph? Now the title is black but the other texts are grey. I'm creating a Hexbin graph using Pandas plot. I have already tried

```
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'text.color': 'black'})
```

As I understood from http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html But it doesn't work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 22}                          
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)

t = pessoas.plot.hexbin(x='qteViagens',y='qteDestUnicos',cmap=plt.cm.jet,gridsize=20,norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(),colorbar=False)
t.set_xlabel('Number of Trips in Period')
t.set_ylabel('Number of Unique Destinations')
t.set_title('Number of Users')
```

[Matplotlib Hexbin graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnip3.png)

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the color of the axis one might do

```
axes.xaxis.label.set_color("yellow")

axes.yaxis.label.set_color("green")
```

[image]

Alternatively, one can pass the color of the labels when creating them with [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html), such as

```
ax.set_xlabel('Number of Trips in Period', color='yellow')
```